# Counting numbers of possible solutions

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinations

For the equation $\displaystyle x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=n$ there are $\displaystyle \binom{4+n}{4}$ solutions.

But what about the equation  $\displaystyle x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5=n$ ?

Assuming $\displaystyle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,n$ positive integers

Is there a nice way to calculate this?

Comment: Assuming all $x$ are integers?

Comment: yes,added this to the question thanks :)

Comment: judging by the first line looks like they are all whole numbers , and order is important when counting solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm ignoring negative integers)

You need to first factorise $n$ into powers of primes:
$$n = p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \ldots p_m^{k_m}.$$
Then your $x_1, \ldots x_5$ must be composed of the same primes. For each $p_i$, the powers of $p_i$ in $x_1, \ldots, x_5$ must be at least $0$ and sum to $k_i$. Moreover, these sums can operate independently. So, using the formula for the sums, there are precisely
$$\binom{4 + k_1}{k_1}\binom{4 + k_2}{k_2}\ldots \binom{4 + k_m}{k_m}$$
ways to choose $x_1, \ldots, x_5$ to product to $n$.

As an example, consider $n = 72 = 2^3 \cdot 3^2$. Then, if $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5 = n$, we may write $x_i = 2^{a_i} \cdot 3^{b_i}$ for non-negative integers $a_i, b_i$. Therefore, we have,
$$2^3 \cdot 3^2 = x_1 x_2 x_3 x_4 x_5 = 2^{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5} \cdot 3^{b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5},$$
which implies,
\begin{align*}
a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + a_4 + a_5 &= 3 \\
b_1 + b_2 + b_3 + b_4 + b_5 &= 2.
\end{align*}
There are $\binom{4 + 3}{4}$ ways to choose the $a_i$'s and $\binom{4 + 2}{4}$ ways to choose the $b_i$'s. Choosing $a_i$'s does not affect the possible choices for the $b_i$'s, so the total number of choices is $\binom{7}{4} \cdot \binom{6}{4}$.

Comment: Awesome answer and explanation,thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The following article on http://oeis.org

http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Enrique_P%C3%A9rez_Herrero/Piltz

calls this function $\tau_5(n)$ a Piltz function
the following sequence might be relevant

http://oeis.org/A061200.

Comment: Great links,thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ are positive integers, then the number of solutions depends on the number of and the nature  of the factors of $n$.

For example, if $n$ is a prime number, then there are $5$ solutions: $(1, 1, 1, 1, n), (1, 1, 1, n, 1), (1, 1, n, 1, 1), (1, n, 1, 1, 1), (n, 1, 1, 1, 1)$.

For an algorithmic perspective on this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543342/algorithm-to-list-all-possible-ways-to-break-a-number-into-k-factors).